# C# asynchronous functions - does await immediately start a task on a new thread?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I'm refactoring some C# code for asynchronous operation, but I'm afraid I'm not understanding in depth what is going on with the C# await instructions. I have a method that does some potentially lengthy processing and will need to run 200 times in a row:

```
public LanDeviceInfo GetLanDBData(LanDeviceInfo device)
```

And I create an asynchronous version which uses it:

```
public async Task<LanDeviceInfo> GetLanDBDataAsync(LanDeviceInfo device)
{
    var deviceInfo = await Task.Run(() => GetLanDBData(device));
    return deviceInfo;
}
```

And, on the UI, on the click of a button, I'm running it with the await keyword inside of a loop:

```
    private async void GenerateCommissioningFile()
    {
            foreach (VacFwPLCInfo thisPLC in filteredPLCList)
            {
                try
                {
                    plcCount++;
                    buttonGenerateComFile.Text = $"LanDB ({plcCount}/{filteredPLCList.Count})";
                    await lanDB.GetLanDBDataAsync(thisPLC);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    thisPLC.Error = true;
                }
            }
    }
```

All of this works fine, the function gets called in an asynchronous way and my UI doesn't get blocked.

Now, what I don't understand is why defining the GetLanDBDataAsync function as follows compiles fine but doesn't work and blocks the UI thread:

```
public async Task<LanDeviceInfo> GetLanDBDataAsync(LanDeviceInfo device)
{
    return GetLanDBData(device);
}
```

From what I understand, this should work as well. Defining this function using the async modifier with the Task return type would make the compiler automatically generate a task which would be returned whenever `GetLanDBDataAsync()` is called. Then calling `await GetLanDBDataAsync()` from `GenerateCommissioningFile()` would automatically make it run in a new thread and not block the UI. Why must I manually create a task to run `GetLanDBData()` and await it inside `GetLanDBDataAsync()` when `GenerateCommissioningFile()`, which runs on the UI thread, is already awaiting the asynchronous function? I feel like I'm really missing something here ;)

Thanks!

Comment: Not a proper answer, but in the last snippet case you should not even use `async`, `async` is to allow use of `await` inside the function.

Comment: And the last `GetLanDBDataAsync` blocks the UI thread since the function calls _synchronously_  `GetLanDBData`, and thus it doesn't make a difference that it is marked as "async" or not, or even that it returns a Task.

Comment: `await` awaits an already executing operation. Neither `async` nor `await` start that operation. Your code doesn't use asynchronous execution though, it executes the database code in a separate thread. And results in a bug, as `async void` can't be awaited. Use async operations instead of `Task.Run` and `async Task` for async operations that return no results

Comment: What does `GetLanDBData` do? That's the most important code. If you connect to a database you can replace `Open` with `OpenAsync`, `ExecuteReader` with `ExecuteReaderAsync` etc and get real asynchronous execution

Comment: Recommended reading: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this function:

```
public async Task<LanDeviceInfo> GetLanDBDataAsync(LanDeviceInfo device)
{
    return GetLanDBData(device);
}
```

compiler should issue a warning: "this async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously". Compiler will convert this method to something like this:

```
public Task<LanDeviceInfo> GetLanDBDataAsync(LanDeviceInfo device)
{
    var result = GetLanDBData(device);
    return Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

So indeed compiler generated a task and returned it, but not in a way you expected. The whole method runs synchronously on caller (UI) thread and so blocks it the same way as `GetLanDBData` does.

Task basically represents some work in progress (or even already completed, as shown above with `Task.FromResult`), with ability to check the status of said work, and being notified when work is completed (or failed). It doesn't necessary has any relation to threads.

`await someTask` very rougly means - IF `someTask` is not already completed - then execute the rest of the method some time later, when `someTask` actually completes. It doesn't start any new tasks, nor does it create any new threads.

Your working version:

```
public async Task<LanDeviceInfo> GetLanDBDataAsync(LanDeviceInfo device)
{
    var deviceInfo = await Task.Run(() => GetLanDBData(device));
    return deviceInfo;
}
```

very rougly means -

1. create a task representing the whole operation inside `GetLanDBDataAsync` method. Let's name that `taskResult`.
2. Queue `GetLanDBData` to be executed on thread pool (because that's what documentation of `Task.Run` says it does, not just because "it's a task"). Task returned from `Task.Run` represents this pending operation.
3. Now, if task returned from `Task.Run` is not yet completed (it does not) - return our `taskResult` (representing whole operation) back to the caller.
4. When some time later task returned from `Task.Run` completes - we execute the rest of the code. In this case, result of `Task.Run` is just forwarded to our `taskResult`, because the rest of the code is just `return deviceInfo`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm beginning to understand. So a Task does not always spawn a new thread, it's simply a way to run code asynchronously and be able to use 'await' to execute a callback once that code is finished?

In that case, what exactly is the intermediary Task that the compiler has automatically created as the return for GetLanDBDataAsync (in the version that works)?

Comment: Yes, Task represents some work in progress and provides ways to check for result, and notify about the result. For the version that works, compiler generated task which basically completes after your `Task.Run` completes. You could replace that with `return Task.Run(...)` and removing "async" keyword (it's needed only if you have await) to achieve same result.

Comment: There is one more thing to await keyword. By default, if there is "synchronization context" available - it executes continuation (everything after await) on that context. What that means in your case is: because you run that on UI thread - continuation after `await` will be executed on UI thread.

Comment: Good answer, but I think the comments you added would be better placed in the body of the answer.

Comment: @RodrigoFerreira I've tried to explain a bit more in edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, things make much more sense now! 

Also, after a bit more reading, I think I understood how the compiler generates the task that it returns in ```public async Task<LanDeviceInfo> GetLanDBDataAsync(LanDeviceInfo device)```. Apparently it uses the TaskCompletionSource class and returns the Task that the class provides, signaling it as complete once the awaited task is finished.